# Email handling in php for Property Management system

Tags: php, html

I going to build Property Management system. If the client send to the mail support@example.com that mail needs to come my system and system will get the information and create a number for the mail and send it again to admin. I search this many times but the problem is i don't know the keywords. Please help me find any keywords and advise.

Comment: I may not understand fully what you're trying to accomplish, maybe you are looking for something like an email ticket system? http://osticket.com/

Comment: @Chris - yes. thatz right. :)